# Checkbox appears as Text Box

Tags: html, css

Html File:

```
<html>

<body style="background-color: #FAECC1;">
    <table style="height:100%">
        <tr>
            <td style="background-color: #98694F ; width:150px ">
                <nav>
                    <ul>
                        <li>
                            <a href="../r/exp1.html" style="color: white;" ">Home</a></li>

                        <li><a href="../r/ep2.html " style="color: white; ">Order Here</a></li>


                    </ul>
                </nav>
            </td>

            <td>
                <div class="row ">
                    <div class="col-75 ">
                        <div class="container ">
                            <form action="/action_page.php ">

                                <div class="row ">
                                    <div class="col-50 ">
                                        <h3>Billing Address</h3>
                                        <label for="fname "> Full Name</label>
                                        <input type="text " id="fname " name="firstname " placeholder="John M. Doe ">
                                        <label for="email "> Email</label>
                                        <input type="text " id="email " name="email " placeholder="john@example.com ">
                                        <label for="adr "> Address</label>
                                        <input type="text " id="adr " name="address " placeholder="15th Street, Bandra ">
                                        <label for="city "></i> City</label>
                                        <input type="text " id="city " name="city " placeholder="Mumbai ">

                                        <div class="row ">
                                            <div class="col-50 ">
                                                <label for="state ">State</label>
                                                <input type="text " id="state " name="state " placeholder="Maharashtra ">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-50 ">
                                                <label for="zip ">Zip</label>
                                                <input type="text " id="zip " name="zip " placeholder="400101 ">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                    <div class="col-50 ">
                                        <h3>Payment</h3>
                                        <label for="fname ">Accepted Cards</label>
                                        <div class="icon-container ">
                                        </div>
                                        <label for="cname ">Name on Card</label>
                                        <input type="text " id="cname " name="cardname " placeholder="John More Doe ">
                                        <label for="ccnum ">Credit card number</label>
                                        <input type="text " id="ccnum " name="cardnumber " placeholder="1111-2222-3333-4444 ">
                                        <label for="expmonth ">Exp Month</label>
                                        <input type="text " id="expmonth " name="expmonth " placeholder="September ">

                                        <div class="row ">
                                            <div class="col-50 ">
                                                <label for="expyear ">Exp Year</label>
                                                <input type="text " id="expyear " name="expyear " placeholder="2018 ">
                                            </div>
                                            <div class="col-50 ">
                                                <label for="cvv ">CVV</label>
                                                <input type="text " id="cvv " name="cvv " placeholder="352 ">
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                    </div>

                                </div>
                                <label>
                            <input type="text " placeholder="Yes "> Shipping address same as billing
                        </label>

                            </form>
                        </div>
                    </div>

                    <div class="col-25 ">
                        <div class="container ">
                            <h4>Cart

                                <b></h4></b>
                                
                                <div>
                                <form>
                                    <input type="checkbox " id="vehicle1 " name="vehicle1 " value="Bike ">
                                    <label for="vehicle1 "> I have a bike</label><br>

                                    <div>
                                    <input type="text " placeholder="No of cups ">
                                    <label for="coff1 "><pre> Expresso       Rs.150/shot</pre> </label><br>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="text " placeholder="No of cups ">
                                    <label for="coof2 "><pre> Normal         Rs.100</pre> </label><br>
                                </div>
                                <div>
                                    <input type="text " placeholder="No of cups ">
                                    <label for="coff3 "><pre> Latte          Rs.125</pre></label>
                                </div>
                                </form>
                            </div>
                                <hr>
                                <p>Total <span class="price "><b></b></span></p>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <a href="../r/ep3.html "> <button type="button " style="background-color:#E9CBA7 ">Submit Order!</button>
                </a>
                
            </td>
        </tr>
    </table>
    <h1>Show Checkboxes</h1>

    <div>
    <form>
      <input type="checkbox " id="vehicle1 " name="vehicle1 " value="Bike ">
      <label for="vehicle1 "> I have a bike</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox " id="vehicle2 " name="vehicle2 " value="Car ">
      <label for="vehicle2 "> I have a car</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox " id="vehicle3 " name="vehicle3 " value="Boat ">
      <label for="vehicle3 "> I have a boat</label><br><br>
      <input type="submit " value="Submit ">
    </form>
</div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Please focus on the last part which is

```
   <div>
    <form>
      <input type="checkbox " id="vehicle1 " name="vehicle1 " value="Bike ">
      <label for="vehicle1 "> I have a bike</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox " id="vehicle2 " name="vehicle2 " value="Car ">
      <label for="vehicle2 "> I have a car</label><br>
      <input type="checkbox " id="vehicle3 " name="vehicle3 " value="Boat ">
      <label for="vehicle3 "> I have a boat</label><br><br>
      <input type="submit " value="Submit ">
    </form>
</div>
    
</body>

</html>
```

Apparently, the above checkbox shown as text boxes
[image: Error]

I copied this part and saved it on another HTML file then it gives me the proper output. it is not working with my original code which I have given above.

If anyone can help me then it will be a great help to me.
Thank you for giving your valuable time towards my problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There's an unnecessary space in the value of each attribute.
Replace that code with this

```html
<html>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
    <label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2" name="vehicle2" value="Car">
    <label for="vehicle2"> I have a car</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3" name="vehicle3" value="Boat">
    <label for="vehicle3"> I have a boat</label><br><br>
    <input type="submit" value="Submit">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

You just need to get rid of the space in "checkbox". You should get rid of the other spaces too:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1" name="vehicle1" value="Bike">
      <label for="vehicle1"> I have a bike</label><br>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this code

```html
<html>
<body>
  <form>
    <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle1 " name="vehicle1 " value="Bike ">
    <label for="vehicle1 "> I have a bike</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle2 " name="vehicle2 " value="Car ">
    <label for="vehicle2 "> I have a car</label><br>
    <input type="checkbox" id="vehicle3 " name="vehicle3 " value="Boat ">
    <label for="vehicle3"> I have a boat</label><br><br>
    <input type="submit " value="Submit ">
  </form>
</body>
</html>
```